# Pass through user parameter and fallback to default

Tags: powershell

How do I fallback to default value inside a subroutine? Consider having `1.ps1` as follows:

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [ValidateSet('A', 'B')]
    [String]
    $What,

    $Target
)

function CallA {
   param(
       $Target = 'default for A'
   )

   Write-Host $Target
}

function CallB {
   param(
       $Target = 'default for B'
   )

   Write-Host $Target
}

&"Call$What" -Target $Target
```

If I call it from powershell console like so: `./1 -What A` I'll get empty line, whereas the intention would be to get `default for A` as the result.

I could of course check if `$Target` is `$null` in each function but I find this way being cumbersome. Is there a better way except for explicit check?

Comment: If none other solution, one would be to dynamically create the call and check for `$null` there, and only pass the parameter if it is not null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) - conditionally add the `-Target` parameter value to a dictionary and pass that to the inner function call with the `@` splat operator:

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [ValidateSet('A', 'B')]
    [String]
    $What,

    $Target
)

function CallA {
   param(
       $Target = 'default for A'
   )

   Write-Host $Target
}

function CallB {
   param(
       $Target = 'default for B'
   )

   Write-Host $Target
}

# Create a dictionary to hold the parameter arguments we want to "splat"
$callParams = @{}

# Conditionally add parameter arguments to the dictionary
if($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Target')){
  # -Target argument was passed, pass it on to in inner function call
  $callParams['Target'] = $Target
}

# Call function with splatted arguments
&"Call$What" @callParams
```